# Jump to nearest pair of brackets with %

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement

I'm looking for a way to change the behaviour of the `%` key. I know by default it will move the cursor to the corresponding parenthesis or brace, but I'm wondering if I can have it jump to the nearest similar character in the event I use it while on a non-bracket char.
i.e.

```
    Lam a -> k $ VClosure (\v k' -> eval (v:env) a k')
                                    ^
```

(where `^` is the cursor position) should move the cursor to the left parenthesis a couple chars to the right, after which the normal behaviour applies.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1):

Make use of a standard "matchit" plugin which provides `[%` and `]%` commands.

To enable "matchit" simply add `packadd! matchit` to your vimrc (or execute `packadd matchit` in your current Vim session).